# Meta-data addition into Manifest file

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I work on Facebook integration in my application and would like to use code below in Manifest file in the shown place.

```
</activity>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
</application>
```

During `Gradle` sync I got a lot of error messages. For example:

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.

Comment: Your error is rather connected to a style definition - I don't believe that the meta-data tag causes this issue. Do you use the support library?

Comment: @Trinimon : I added only `facebook-android-sdk`, nothing else changed and it was working before this.

Comment: If you added an external library: may be you missed to add some dependencies, for instance the support library or other libs? Did you check the API target level as well. Guess you need something that includes the Material design (i.e. >= 21).

Comment: Facebook says API level 15 is enough and I set this already.